# First install of Adobe CQ 5.5 product with Oracle 11.2 XE

Tags: oracle, adobe, aem, ojdbc

I'm configuring Adobe CQ 5.5 for a first installation and I have problems because in the installation process, CQ didn't found the Oracle Driver. I need to use a relational database (Oracle) rather than the Tar predefined system. In the Adobe CQ documentation, says that it need to be configured before installation.

But my problem is when CQ installs, it didn't found the driver of Oracle database.

I have configured the file repository.xml as:

```
    ...
    ...
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe" />
        <param name="user" value="crx" />
        <param name="password" value="admin" />
        <param name="schema" value="oracle" />
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_" />
    </PersistenceManager>
    ...
    ...
```

The problem is when Adobe CQ try to find the Oracle Driver, it fails with this message in logs:

```
18.05.2013 17:25:37.946 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl failed to start Repository: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager
...
...
Caused by: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Could not load JDBC driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found by com.day.crx.sling.server [45]
```

And finally the installation stops.

I tried to install only a Jackrabbit repository with this configuration, and it runs. I put the ojdbc6.jar jar file in the jre7/lib/ext and in Java JAVA_PATH.

Anyone know the procedure for the detection of the driver during the installation of Adobe CQ 5.5?

Thanks and best regards!

Juan Carlos.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you want people to know your name, rather than entering at the bottom of each post I suggest you edit your profile.  You can do this by clicking on `user2397163` where it appears at the top of this page, then find and click on the `edit` button - you can then set your display name, real name, email, etc.